# Converting from `std::array<std::variant<>>` to `void*`

Tags: c++, array, casting

I'm doing some work with Vulkan, in this I need to pass a set of values of various types.

Currently I'm using `std::array<std::variant<>>` in my interface, but I must pass Vulkan a `void*`.

To convert to the `void*` I use this function:

```cpp
template <uint32_t Size>
void* voidArray(std::array<std::variant<uint32_t,float>,Size>& array, uint32_t size) {
    char* bytes = new char[size];
    uint32_t byteCounter = 0;
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<array.size();++i) {
        if(float* flt = std::get_if<float>(&array[i])) {
            *reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytes+byteCounter) = *flt;
            byteCounter += sizeof(float);
        }
        else if(uint32_t* uin = std::get_if<uint32_t>(&array[i])) {
            *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(bytes+byteCounter) = *uin;
            byteCounter += sizeof(uint32_t);
        }
    }
    void* data = static_cast<void*>(bytes);
    return data;
}
```

I get the `size` variable earlier within a larger function (names are a little more context specific):

```cpp
// std::array<std::variant<uint32_t,float>,NumPushConstants>& pushConstants
std::optional<uint32_t> pushConstantSize = std::nullopt; // later used for `size`
auto size_fn = [](auto variant) -> uint32_t {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(variant)>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<uint32_t, T>) { return sizeof(uint32_t); }
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<float, T>) { return sizeof(float);}
};
pushConstantSize = std::accumulate(pushConstants.begin(),pushConstants.end(),0,
    [size_fn](uint32_t acc, auto variant) { return std::move(acc) + std::visit(size_fn,variant); }
);
```

Both of these implementations, most prominently the first rouse my suspicion of being bad.

Are they bad? Is there a better way? Am I missing something?

Comment: It would be nice to have some more information (and code). Why do you need the variants? Why not use two separate arrays?

Comment: @user673679 Using variants allows flexibility in ordering, more closely matches the real structure and better allows for possible further templating in allowing the array to contain a mixture of any user-specified types (Vulkan in taking a `void*` means the array can contain any types, I have for now simply set 2 very common types I am using), is my current thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to provide overall feedback, since you don't want to provide any details. There's probably a much simpler way to structure all of this.

But some things about the specific code:

---

**don't do manual memory management**:

```
char* bytes = new char[size];
```

I hope this gets `delete[]`d somewhere. We should use a `std::vector` instead, and get a pointer from `vector.data()` when we actually need to.

---

**use std::byte in C++17**:

```
char* bytes = new char[size];
```

If we have it, we should use `std::byte` instead of `char` (since we're dealing with object representations in memory).

---

**use memcpy, not reinterpret_cast; simplify**:

```
    if(float* flt = std::get_if<float>(&array[i])) {
        *reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytes+byteCounter) = *flt;
        byteCounter += sizeof(float);
    }
    else if(uint32_t* uin = std::get_if<uint32_t>(&array[i])) {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(bytes+byteCounter) = *uin;
        byteCounter += sizeof(uint32_t);
    }
```

Due to "strict aliasing rules" I don't think this is technically correct (even if it apparently works). Our `char` array doesn't have floats in it, so we shouldn't pretend that it does and copy in a float. We should instead use `std::memcpy` to copy the underlying representation of the float into the array.

Note also that we're doing the exact same thing for both types, so we could probably do something like:

```
std::apply([&] (auto const& var) {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(var)>;
    std::memcpy(bytes + byteCounter, static_cast<void const*>(&var), sizeof(T));
    byteCounter += sizeof(T);
}, array[i]);
```

---

**same again (again)**:

The same thing is true of the second code snippet:

```
std::optional<uint32_t> pushConstantSize = std::nullopt; // later used for `size`
auto size_fn = [](auto variant) -> uint32_t {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(variant)>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<uint32_t, T>) { return sizeof(uint32_t); }
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<float, T>) { return sizeof(float);}
};
pushConstantSize = std::accumulate(pushConstants.begin(),pushConstants.end(),0,
    [size_fn](uint32_t acc, auto variant) { return std::move(acc) + std::visit(size_fn,variant); }
);
```

We don't need the `if` statements:

```
auto size_fn = [] (auto const& var) {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(var)>;
    return sizeof(T);
};
std::size_t size = std::accumulate(pushConstants.begin(), pushConstants.end(), std::size_t{ 0 },
    [=](std::size_t acc, auto var) { return acc + std::visit(size_fn, var); }
);
```

`std::move` won't help with a trivially copyable type, and we should be using `std::size_t` for the size.

The `optional` also seems redundant; we always have a size, even if the array is empty.

This snippet should be made a whole complete function by itself.

Comment: Strict aliasing isn’t an issue when using `((un)signed) char` (or `std::byte`, which is basically just a strongly-typedef-ed `unsigned char`); there’s a specific exemption just for those. What *is* an issue, and what is never dealt with anywhere in the code, is alignment. Using `std::memcpy()` will dodge that issue *somewhat* (where simply casting and assigning won’t), but even if it doesn’t bite you in *this* code, it will almost certainly bite you elsewhere.

Comment: Good points! I had some issues with the implementation of `std::apply` and I instead went this approach for that part instead https://pastebin.com/LpYxiQ2z.